# Most efficient way to delete ndb query results

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

Here is my current method:

```
def delete_up_to_10000(query):
    for i in range(10):
        keys = query.fetch(1000, keys_only=True, deadline=40, batch_size=1000)
        ndb.delete_multi(keys)
```

My question is, **Is it possible to delete the results of the query without actually having to fetch the keys? Shouldn't that be possible?**

Here are a few decision points around my current solution:

- I decided not to go over 1000 at a time to reduce memory usage.
- I'm calling this method a few times a minute from various CRON tasks.
- I have certain queries for data that is safe to delete based on how old the data is and what type of data it is - I have billions of entities currently.
- I'm hoping a few years from now, data will still be purged at a faster rate than it is written to the datastore - so will set the delete rate to be about 100 times that of the current write rate.

Comment: Results of a keys only query are keys.

Comment: yeah - but still seems like overhead for me to have to ask megastore / bigtable for the list of keys only to then tell megastore / bigtable to delete those items - seems like I could save some network by just telling megastore / bigtable to delete whatever it finds from the query and not report back

Comment: Consider using `delete_multi_async` each time through the loop -- save all the resulting `Futures` in a list and `Future.wait_all` on them (if you even need that!-) after the loop.  It should improve your throughput.

Comment: Thanks @AlexMartelli I've switched to fetch_page although I could be using the _async version - I think the throughput should be ok with the sync version. I've put my current solution in the answers below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The keys-only query does not retrieve the entities. It looks at the indexes, but only the indexes that you specified in the query.

"Delete" operation, on the other hand, must delete not only the entity itself, it must also delete an entry into each and every index for this entity - whether it's an index for a property or a composite index.

Thus, a query simply does not have all the information necessary to perform a delete operation at the same time. And the hypothetical "delete what you find" operation will be just a shorthand for "find a list of keys, then use these keys to update all indexes and remove an entity itself"." It may remove some overhead, but at the cost of greater complexity.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fetch the keys in order to do the delete. Are you trying to mass delete and are simply spreading it out? You should look into a mapper (ie mapreduce). Its perfect for going through large amounts of datastore entries and deleting. You could run the map job once a day / week to keep your data under control.

Comment: Theres even built in Datastore Admin tool which allows you to easily delete all entities.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my current solution now:

```
def _delete_from_query(query, limit, batch_size=2000):
    delete_count = 0
    next_curs = None
    while True:
        lim = min(batch_size, limit - delete_count)
        keys, next_curs, more = query.fetch_page(
            lim, start_cursor=next_curs, deadline=40, batch_size=lim, keys_only=True
        )
        ndb.delete_multi(keys)
        delete_count += len(keys)
        if not keys or not more or delete_count == limit:
            break
    return delete_count
```

Comment: I use same/similar solution. I'm not sure whether it is guaranteed that fetch_page will return correct page after deleting results from previous batch. E.g. if batch_size = 10, after deleting first 10 keys, will I get the next 10 keys or will new pagination happen, after the removal? I didn't see any problems while testing the solution, but just wondering how fetch_page is working, whether it has pre-emptively determined which keys to be fetched with which page?

Comment: Compared with simple python problem: if we have list of 100 elements and want to return them in batches of 10 elements, then after removing the first 10, the rest of the list is shifted to the left, so if I remove: l[:10] and then remove l[10:20], that would actually remove 20:30, not 10:20, due to the shifting...

Seems like I won't have such issues here, but just wondering whether it is documented somewhere how fetch_page works when items are deleted/added which meet the query criteria...